# Javascript for loop without recalculating array's length

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, syntax

In my Javascript reference book, for loops are optimized in the following way:

```
for( var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i + +) { BODY }
```

Apparently, doing "len = keys.length" prevents the computer from recalculating keys.length each time it goes through the for loop.

I don't understand why the book doesn't write "var len = keys.length" instead of "len = keys.length"? Isn't the book making "len" a global variable, which isn't good if you're trying to nest two for-loops that loop through two arrays?

E.g.

```
for( var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i + +) { 
     for (var i = 0; len = array2.length; i < len; i++) {
     }
}
```

Source: Flanagan, David (2011-04-18). JavaScript: The Definitive Guide: Activate Your Web Pages (Definitive Guides) (Kindle Locations 6992-6998). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Comment: `var i = 0, len = keys.length` is shorthand for `var i=0;` and `var len=key.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain variable declarations like this

```
var i = 0, foo="bar", hello = "world"
```

Which is close to the same thing as

```
var i = 0;
var foo = "bar";
var hello = "world";
```

So this

```
for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++)
```

Is the same as

```
var len = keys.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

I like to avoid .length altogether and use something like

```
var keys = /* array or nodelist */, key, i;
for(i = 0; key = keys[i]; i++)
```

This will cause the for loop to end as soon as key resolves to undefined.
Now you can use `key` instead of `keys[i]`

As a side note, your second example would never work as all of the variables defined in the first for statement would be overwritten by the second, yielding unexpected results. You can nest for loops, but you have to use different variable names.

Comment: I used to use and promote a loop style very similar to your last example. However, I don't use it any more. Surprisingly, it is *much* slower than a conventional loop in modern browsers, because reading past the end of the array causes the entire array to become de-optimized. Here are some [test results](http://jsperf.com/mikes-loops/2) for various kinds of loops.

Answer (score 1):

AS Ankit correctly  mentioned in the comments of the question, it is a shorthand. And moreover, if I am correct, javascript is functionally scoped and not block scoped, so you are  overwriting the len declared in the outer for loop while re-declaring it in the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript each time you instantiate it's a heavy cost. Using one var and short hand commas to create multiple variables is much more efficient.

Your example using only one var to create a variable.

```
 for (var i = 0, len = array2.length; i < len; i++) {
      //loop
 }
```

The alternative is to var up the len variable outside the loop.

```
 var len = array2.length; 
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      //loop
 }
```

Now you have two separate "var" instances.

I personally like to declare my var at the beginning.

```
 var len = array2.length,
     i = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
      //First loop
 }

 //So if I use more than one for loop in a routine I can just reuse i
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      //Second loop
 }
```

Hope that helps explain.

Comment: Whether you use one `var` or two won't affect performance in the slightest. It's really a matter of which style you prefer. (Also note a typo in your first example.)